# Check if User is Anonymous in Firestore Cloud Function

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

When a user is authenticated I trigger a cloud Firestore Cloud Function below;

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase)

exports.createUserAccount = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user) => {
    const uid = user.uid
    const firstName = user.firstName
    const familyName = user.familyName
    const displayName = user.displayName
    const email = user.email
    const photoURL = user.photoURL

    const newUser = admin.firestore().doc(`/users/${uid}`)

    return newUser.set({
        firstName: firstName,
        familyName: familyName,
        displayName: displayName,
        email: email,
        photoURL: photoURL,
    })
})
```

I run into an issue when a user is logged in anonymously.  I have tried adding a `const isAnonymous = user.isAnonymous` and then returning it under;

```
return newUser.set({
    isAnonymous: isAnonymous,
```

## ERROR LOG IN CONSOLE

```
Error: Value for argument "data" is not a valid Firestore document. Cannot use "undefined" as a Firestore value (found in field isAnonymous).
```

My question is how do I check if the user is anonymously logged in or not through a Firebase Cloud Function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [UserRecord](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.UserRecord.html) object delivered to your auth function will never have an isAnonymous property on it.  That's why it's always taking the value `undefined`.  Check the link to the API documentation to see what's there.  I'm not sure how you came to the conclusion that it should be there.

Each authentication provider that has verified an account is present in the [providerData](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.UserRecord.html#provider-data) array property of the UserRecord object.  You should look through that array to check if it's an anonymous account.  Specifically, you should be checking the [providerId](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.UserInfo.html#providerid) field of each UserInfo object in the `providerData` array.  I'm not 100% certain if this is the correct approach, but from what I'm observing, an anonymous account will have an **empty** providerData array, since it's not been verified by any auth providers.

Comment: I assumed the isAnonymous would give a boolean value.  I have got the providerData and it is, as you mentioned an empty array.  I will amend my function to check for an empty array in the providerData and continue my logic from there.  Many thanks.  I'd request adding an isAnonymous boolean though as it appears more logical than checking for an empty array.

Comment: The API could be be better for sure, please submit a feature request for that.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are using email-based authentication (email+pass & OAuth) then you can simply check

```
if (user.email !== null){ 
  // Run this code if the user is not anonymous
}
```

[Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.UserRecord#email)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no direct API for checking if a user is anonymous using the firebase admin sdk. By checking that a user has been active and don't have any connected login providers I believe it should work however.

```
const user = await admin.auth().getUser('Bp7DmEl5HKcDKrQr7QFVnQXS8FH1')
const hasBeenActive = user.metadata.lastSignInTime != null
const hasProviders = user.providerData.length > 0
const isAnonymous = hasBeenActive && !hasProviders
```

Note that the reason for the active check is to filter out users who are created manually using either the firebase console or with the admin sdk. Depending on your use case you might want to consider them anonymous as well.